# Is it accurate to use hyphens after people's names? (John - , Hi John -)

Tags: grammar, business-writing

I've seen a number of people especially in business settings use hyphens after names while writing or addressing other individuals. Is this accurate? e.g. `John - I've been trying to reach you` or `Hi John - I've been trying to reach you`

Comment: What medium? What country? To close colleagues, bosses, underlings, or customers? To people you know well or have never met? What do you mean "accurate" - common, grammatical, ambiguous, in accordance with a specific style guide?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very informal way of indicating a break.  In fiction one would use it in dialog.

Consequently it would be suitable to use in a text message, and perhaps an informal email.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to would be an em-dash.

From [the CMS's site](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html):

> The em dash has several uses. It allows, in a manner similar to parentheses, an additional thought to be added within a sentence by sort of breaking away from that sentence—as I’ve done here. Its use or misuse for this purpose is a matter of taste, and subject to the effect on the writer’s or reader’s “ear.”

I would read CH6 of the Chicago Manual of Style for more information.